# Add a sidebar in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm building Windows Phone 8.1 application and I want a sidebar like in android apps. How can I do it?

I tried [this](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html) example, but doesn't compile and manipulation event's do not fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is very simple example with velocity handling.

Make sure to set grid's `Manipulation` property to `All`.

Change grid's background from `DarkSalmon` to `Transparent`.

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Canvas Name="RootCanvas">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="MoveAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="Sidebar" d:IsOptimized="True" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Grid Name="Sidebar" Background="DarkSalmon" Width="360" Height="640" Canvas.Left="-340" ManipulationDelta="Sidebar_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationCompleted="Sidebar_ManipulationCompleted">
        <Grid Background="DarkSlateBlue" Margin="0,0,20,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Content="Mailbox" />
                <Button Content="Calendar" />
                <Button Content="Tasks" />
                <Button Content="Documents" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

**Code-behind**

```
private bool _triggerCompleted;

    private const double SideMenuCollapsedLeft = -340;
    private const double SideMenuExpandedLeft = 0;

    private void Sidebar_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _triggerCompleted = true;

        double finalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Sidebar) + e.Delta.Translation.X;
        if (finalLeft < -340 || finalLeft > 0)
            return;

        Canvas.SetLeft(Sidebar, finalLeft);

        if (e.IsInertial && e.Velocities.Linear.X > 1)
        {
            _triggerCompleted = false;
            e.Complete();
            MoveLeft(SideMenuExpandedLeft);
        }

        if (e.IsInertial && e.Velocities.Linear.X < -1)
        {
            _triggerCompleted = false;
            e.Complete();
            MoveLeft(SideMenuCollapsedLeft);
        }

        if (e.IsInertial && Math.Abs(e.Velocities.Linear.X) <= 1)
            e.Complete();
    }

    private void Sidebar_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_triggerCompleted == false)
            return;

        double finalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Sidebar);

        if (finalLeft > -170)
            MoveLeft(SideMenuExpandedLeft);
        else
            MoveLeft(SideMenuCollapsedLeft);
    }

    private void MoveLeft(double left)
    {
        double finalLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(Sidebar);

        Storyboard moveAnivation = ((Storyboard)RootCanvas.Resources["MoveAnimation"]);
        DoubleAnimation direction = ((DoubleAnimation)((Storyboard)RootCanvas.Resources["MoveAnimation"]).Children[0]);

        direction.From = finalLeft;

        moveAnivation.SkipToFill();

        direction.To = left;

        moveAnivation.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

http://slideview.codeplex.com/

Hope it will help.