# How to create app bar slide menu in windows universal app

Tags: c#, windows, menu, win-universal-app, slide

Please help me to choose the right tool for this task (windows universal app, c#). I need to do a translucent menu, which is come out from the left when we push app bar button and can be closed back. Something nearly like this:

[image: example].

What should I use for it? Should it be something like dynamic panel with hidden/visible visibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206615/add-a-sidebar-in-windows-phone-8-1-application

Comment: SplitView is your friend here. Microsoft have a [sample on GiHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation) on how to use the new SplitView control in your UWP apps.

Comment: The same hamburger menu available on GitHub [check this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVsajohErQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2015/06/01/windows-10-build-your-first-hamburger-menu.aspx

For translucent menu, you can use the background alpha channel.

If you prefer a video guide, you can follow https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-021-Implementing-a-Simple-Hamburger-Navigation-Menu . This has an example that you can download.

Answer (score 3):

The UWP control you're looking for is the SplitView control which should be used in this context. Microsoft have [a sample on their GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlNavigation) which shows how this can be implemented easily.

[Jerry Nixon has a great blog post](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html) on the best methods for implementing this control into your app also.

Comment: Thank you very much too!